# GWT what is going on with my DatePicker?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, datepicker, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-dev-mode

I've upgraded to GWT 2.7 and also upgraded my Eclipse plug-ins.  When testing an existing Web App to see what might need to be fixed, I noticed my DatePicker looked off.  It's almost as if it does not have any style at all.

Here is how it looked previously:

[image]

And this is how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was missing the following in my *.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
```

Everything is good now